# CKeditor does not load in laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ckeditor

I have a problem I made some changes yesterday to my website and this morning the CKeditor in my project was not working anymore!

> This is at the bottom on app.blade.php in the layouts folder

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'ck_editor' );
    </script>
```

> This is in my change project view.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
           ...
            <div class="form-group row mb-2">
                <label for="beschrijving" class="offset-md-2 col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-left">Omschrijving:</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <textarea name="ck_editor" id="" class="form-control" maxlength="500" rows="3" required>{{$data->beschrijving}}</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
           ...
@endsection
```

This worked before I do not know what went wrong....

Comment: check your console you must be getting some error there

Answer (score 0):

set id value and then run

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea name="ck_editor" id="ck_editor" class="form-control" maxlength="500" rows="3" required>{{$data->beschrijving}}</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: this did not work still getting white space instead of the ckeditor.....